# Is this a proprietary DDR2 interface on this memory module from my Fujitsu laptop?

Tags: memory, toshiba-laptop, ddr2

I would like to upgrade the memory in my Fujitsu laptop but it uses a memory form factor that I've never seen before.

Is this a proprietary connector or is this size defined by some standard that I can use to find an alternative module.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a format of DIMM that I had not previously known about called a MicroDIMM.  MicroDIMMs were apparently only made up to DDR2 at which point SODIMM became the major type used in laptops.

From [Wikipedia: DIMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIMM)

[image]

Found via a [search for the D2P667 part number](https://www.google.com/search?&q=D2P667) which found a "2GB DDR2 MicroDimm Memory Fujitsu Lifebook P1500D P1510" on eBay

Comment: I ordered one of these 2GB modules as it seems to be the correct type. The listing suggested that these will work in a variety of Fujitsu laptops. It must have been fairly common in their sub notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [MicroDIMM](https://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/HYS64Txx.pdf) which is a smaller RAM module used in lightweight devices, thin notebooks, etc.

[image]